# Windows 7 created a Encrypting File System key for me. How can I tell if it's in use?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, encryption

I never knowingly created an encrypted file system, or encrypted files.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/151317/i-started-getting-a-weird-message-encrypting-file-system-back-up-your-file-enc) similar question proposes that it might have been Office 2010, which is a possibility. (Though it's irritating that some install process would have done this for me "behind my back".) The question suggests running `cetmgr.msc` and removing it from the `Personal` category.

But I'm not comfortable doing that without asking the following questions:

1. How can I tell if the key is being used?
2. How can I tell if it's safe to remove the key? (almost implied from (1), but there may be some process I don't know about yet which expects it to be there...)
3. If it turns out I removed it without it being safe, how could I recover?

I would appreciate any insight.

**Edit:**

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/58878/how-to-list-encrypted-files-in-windows-7) provides a useful tip: `encryptionstatus:encrypted` can be used in a Windows Explorer search field to determine if any files are encrypted. I am assuming that this is the key used for that purpose, but I don't know if that's the only way this key is potentially used.

Comment: I doubt windows encrypted anything "behind your back".

Comment: No, but it created the key, which some application could have used without my knowledge.

Comment: >>'I doubt windows encrypted anything "behind your back"'
oh, I can just imagine the next wave of virus and rootkits..

Comment: @Chris: Win7 does encrypt "in your back": for example when extracting files from a .zip that was created on Mac OS X.